# How to Compress and UN-Compress Xml in c# .net for a windows phone 7 app?

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7

i am developing a windows phone 7 application and my service gives a response xml (strings) which i am consuming in the client side (windows phone 7 app)

my pain point is the xml size  is too large(packet size is very large) which is being transferred from services side to client side.

So now, i want to compress the xml which is being as a response from service  and uncompress it in the client side and use it.

can you let me know how  can i  implement this ?

Thnaks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use the GZipWebClient as detailed in the following blog post "Please ship your next Windows Phone app with GZip: speed requests 50-80%":-

http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2012/01/windows-phone-gzip-support-by-morten/